# Numpy operation of arrays with different size

Tags: python, arrays, performance, numpy

```
c=np.array([ 0.  ,  0.2,  0.22,  0.89,  0.99])
rnd = np.random.uniform(low=0.00, high=1.00, size=12)
```

I want to see how many elements in c are smaller than each of the 12 random numbers in rnd. It needs to be in numpy and without the use of any lists so that it's faster.

The output will be an array of 12 elements, each describing how many elements for each of them are small than the corresponding number in rnd.

Comment: please edit your question with an example of expected output

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`broadcasting`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/user/basics.broadcasting.html) after extending `c` from `1D` to a `2D` array verison with [`None/np.newaxis`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html#numpy.newaxis) for performing comparisons on all elements in a vectorized manner and then summing along rows with `.sum(0)` for the counting, like so -

```
(c[:,None] < rnd).sum(0)
```

It seems you can also use the efficient [`np.searchsorted`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.0/reference/generated/numpy.searchsorted.html) like so -

```
np.searchsorted(c,rnd)
```

Comment: Yes that looks great. What's the 'None' stand for?

Comment: Ok, a little follow up question. If the result of your output is then the index for the original c, how can I get the numbers = rnd[(c[:,None] < rnd).sum(0)]. Do I need broadcasting again?

Comment: The result is a count not an index. What exactly do you have in mind? I don't think I understood this follow-up question. Could you elaborate?

Comment: yes the count will then be used as an index, you understood correctly. In fact the count-1

Comment: Yes but c has 5 elements while count has 12

Comment: actually it worked. I think I now understand broadcasting. c[count[:,None]]